# Integral of $(3-x)/(x+2)$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Will someone explain how to solve this integral:
$$\int \frac{3-x}{x+2} dx =\, ?$$

Answer (score 10):

There are a couple of ways to do it. I like this approach: rewrite the numerator as $5-(x+2)$ and then split it into two integrals.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\displaystyle \int \frac{3-x}{x+2} dx=\displaystyle \int\frac{3}{x+2}dx-\bigg[\int \frac{x+2}{x+2}dx-\int\frac{2}{x+2}dx\bigg]$